# Get size/area of google maps search result

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geography

I am developing a business directory site whose search will be driven by Google Maps. Users will be able to search for businesses in their area based on various criteria, but mainly the idea is that if you search for e.g. "plumbers in New Jersey", you'll get a result of all plumbers in New Jersey. However, if you search for "plumbers in Jersey Shore", you should get only the plumbers that operate in Jersey Shore, which for this example would be a suburb or other type of sub-division of greater New Jersey. As an aside, I'm stripping out "plumbers in", and only passing the actual geographic search term, so my actual google maps search is only "New Jersey" or "Jersey Shore". So don't focus on the actual search text itself.

This is my search snippet:

```
var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;//results is google maps search result for address
console.log(results[0]);
map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
map.addMarker({
    lat: latlng.lat(),
    lng: latlng.lng(),
    icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png'
});

var closestmarkers = [];
var MAXDISTANCE = 5;//radius of our search area in km
closestmarkers = find_n_closest_markers(latlng, n, MAXDISTANCE);//see below snippet for function definition
```

This is the javascript that figures out which markers are closest to the searched :

```
function find_n_closest_markers(latlng, n, MAXDISTANCE){
    var lat = latlng.lat();
    var lng = latlng.lng();
    var R = 6371; // radius of earth in km
    var distances = [];
    var closest = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < map.markers.length; i++) {
        var mlat = map.markers[i].position.lat();
        var mlng = map.markers[i].position.lng();
        var dLat = rad(mlat - lat);
        var dLong = rad(mlng - lng);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2)
              * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
              + Math.cos(rad(lat))
              * Math.cos(rad(lat))
              * Math.sin(dLong / 2)
              * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c;

        distances[i] = { distance: d, index: i };
    }
    distances.sort(comparedistances);

    //remove all distances greater than MAXDISTANCE
    toofarindex = -1;
    for (j = 0; j < distances.length; j++)
    {
        if(distances[j].distance >= MAXDISTANCE)
        {
            toofarindex = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (toofarindex != -1)
    {
        distances = distances.splice(0, toofarindex - 1);
    }

    //return first n + 1 items(the closest marker is the one indicating the user's current/preferred location. which doesn't count)
    if (distances.length > n + 1)
    {
        distances = distances.splice(0, n + 1);
    }
    return distances;
}
```

I am not concerned about the actual function. That works 100%. What I'm looking for is how to figure out, based on the search term, what the value of MAXDISTANCE should be. 5 is just a good compromise constant for now, but I need to know that New Jersey is e.g. 20 miles in diameter, whereas Jersey Shore is only 5 miles (those figures come straight out of my ear, not an actual map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults) also returns a viewport and a bounds for the result.  If you *need* a diameter, you can convert one of those to a distance (the width or the height of the bounds will give you a diameter, if not use that bounds to bound your search.

Comment: That sounds promising.

Comment: This is all true but does not provide for the rejection of any extraneous results outside the intended area (as can happen due to the vagaries of address-based search), which is presumably what the OP's "belt-and-braces" approach is intended to achieve.

Comment: Actually, that's about right. If I know what the center and the bounds of the area is, I can calculate MAXDISTANCE, hence I can filter out results outside that radius. Unless I'm not understanding your objection?

Comment: Juann, yes you can filter out anything outside the circle, but what I'm saying is that by using the bounds of the returned result set to calculate that circle's radius, you are not really filtering anything out (well maybe a couple of marginal cases). It would make more sense to use an *independently derived* radius to filter out any grossly inappropriate results (eg plumbers on Jersey, Channel Islands). Don't ask me how to do this, I'm just saying ...

Comment: I was suggesting he use the viewport/bounds returned by the geocoder either directly or translated to a diameter to determine which of _his_ markers are in the area of interest.

Comment: Which is also how I understood it. I first geocode the search location, and only then do I send a list of plumbers to the filtering function, along with the coordinates of the center of that location (latlng) which eliminates all of them which are further than NAXDISTANCE from the center of that location. My point of reference is the center of the map and I discard anything too far away from it.